# Infinite IObservable from Task function and toggle observable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, system.reactive

I have two things : Function that returns `Task<TResult> query` and `IObservable<bool> toggle`. What I want to create is `IObservable<TResult>` that when `toggle` gets `true`, it start an infinite loop where it calls `query` every time and returns it's result. Then, when toggle gets `false`, it should stop the infinite loop.

I did read how to make an infinite loop from task, but I cannot figure out how to `toggle` it on and off. Also, it cannot run the `query` in infinite loop and just filter it. It should not call the query at all if `toggle` is `false`. Also, it would be great if `toggle` gets false, then the resulting observable would not return if `query` was already started. It might also be good idea to cancel the `query` when `toggle` is false, but it is not necessary.

And I would like it to be automatically testable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think does exactly what you want:

```
IObservable<TResult> query =
    toggle
        .Select(b => b
            ? Observable
                .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => SomeFunction()))
                .Repeat()
            : Observable
                .Never<TResult>())
        .Switch();
```

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you, but would you mind looking at my follow up question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993609/infinite-iobservable-from-task-function-and-toggle-observable-with-parameters

Comment: I'm trying to write a test for this function. I replaced `Observable.FromAsync(() => SomeFunction())` with call to `Func<IObservable<TResult>> query` (which is cold observable that returns single item), so I can use `TestScheduler` to test this function, but I'm having problems with `scheduler.Start` method not returning any Messages. Can you verify that this method can be automatically tested?

Comment: Nevermind, got it working. I should not use 0 as timing parameter in OnNext()